# Should the "law" tag be country-specific?

Tags: discussion

When reading [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/building-permits-for-solar-in-the-usa) it struck me that the "law" tag was almost totally useless, and that a "law-usa" tag or similar would be far more helpful for anybody searching for things relevant to that jurisdiction. Initially, then, I thought of suggesting that such tags should always be country-specific.

Then I searched for everything with a "law" tag, and in two out of four cases the questions were along the lines of "in which country..." or similar, where the object was comparing laws between countries. In this case a general "law" tag makes sense.

So I don't really have a suggestion, but I do have a question that could perhaps use discussion, as per the title.

Comment: Also, I hope this is an appropriate issue to raise and an appropriate way to raise it - I've never participated in a meta.* group before ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In general I think that we don't have too many questions that would use the "law" tag (after all this is a site about sustainability); at the moment we have 4/402=1% of questions, so the tag is a pretty decent filter.

I would vote to just keep just the "law" tag as is. If there is a question about the building code of a particular country, then it can still be relevant to someone looking for building codes in another country.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of country specific tags, but I don't like tags such as [law-usa](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-usa). As [Earthling also mentioned](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/172/99) so far there are only a few questions about the law in one particular country, and I don't think that will change soon. However, there are other areas besides law where the question applies to only one specific country or region, for example [this question about produce in Texas](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/29/99).

Right now I think there are too few question to use country specific tags, but if that changes I'd like to see tags with only the country name. So for the law example question, the tags would be [law](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) and [usa](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)